# Is Flutter capable of dynamically loading and building widgets during runtime?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is there any by which I can store multiple dart files on some server and retrieve any one of those file during run-time in such a way that Flutter is able to build a particular widget from the file it receives?

Comment: have a look at this package https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_widget

Comment: On what factor does the build time of those widgets depend?

Comment: I am not sure if you mean the build time or the parsing time but either ways , the technique is relatively new and I really have not enough information,hope that somebody from dart team can answer this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot dynamically load dart files or create new classes, no.

On the other hand, the widget tree is created at runtime, and widgets are composable by nature. So it is totally possible to make a function that deserialize some data into a widget tree.

We could, for example, write a widget tree as an xml/yaml/whatever like so:

```
type: Row
children:
  - type: Container
    color: red
    child:
      - type: Text
        0: hello world
```

And have a function deserialize it into:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Text('hello world'),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: What else do you want?

Comment: No way. That method is too tedious to implement. That's far outside of the scope of an SO answer

Comment: The response is correct (You cannot dynamically load dart files or create new classes), but the suggestion is not appropriate as that will work for widgets that has been already defined in imported packages at compile time (not at all what the asked question intended to solve). The possibility to dynamically load packages will be for sure an addition to this language in the future, at least if they want to enter on the desktop OS world, as in the current state impossible to think about applications that enable "plugins" for example.  Quick codeless newbies mobile focalized language for now.

Answer (score 1):

[Remote flutter widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/rfw) - A mechanism for rendering widgets based on declarative UI descriptions that can be obtained at runtime.